# Why isn't my lazy loading working in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, lazy-loading

When I try to load the lazy loaded modules, screen just turns white.
Here is what i did:

App-routing module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomepageComponent } from './homepage/homepage.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomepageComponent },
  { path: 'minigame1', loadChildren: () => import('./minigame1/minigame1.module').then(m => m.Minigame1Module) },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

For my lazy loaded module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { FallingballComponent } from './fallingball/fallingball.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path:'', component: FallingballComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class Minigame1RoutingModule { }
```

I've double checked the names and it's not an issue....

Comment: where would one even start helping you! Where/how you "load the lazy loaded modules" (component?). I am sure if you get white screen, you will get some exception. Are you familiar with F12? You might find reading the site [help] useful when it comes to [ask], and this question [checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: Please share html from which you are routing

Comment: One point is that `path: ''` should be placed after any specific paths. Only wildcard should come after that.